# Visual Studio Item Templates using custom parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I want to replace the tag **$Customparameter$** with a value passed on my wizard implementation. The item template it's located in  **...Documents\Visual Studio\Item Templates\Zip file** and i'm using **AddFromTemplate(".zip", "CSHARP")** method to load the item template.

My item template has this structure:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{    class $safeitemrootname$ : $customparameter$
     {
     }
}
```

Any Suggestion?
Thanks